# How to add correct chain certificate when acessing url with wget?

Tags: https, wget

There is a site (https://datashare.is.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/10283/3192/CINIC-10.tar.gz) which I know is misconfigured and I can get the new chained certificate from here: https://whatsmychaincert.com/?datashare.ed.ac.uk

How can I add the correct certificate to fetch data from the url using wget

Code to use:

```
# Download the cinic dataset
cd ../..
mkdir -p data/cinic
wget -P 'data/cinic' wget https://datashare.is.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/10283/3192/CINIC-10.tar.gz
cd data/cinic
tar -xzf CINIC-10.tar.gz
rm CINIC-10.tar.gz
```

Note: I don't have sudo access as I am on a server. Also, I am bew to using ssl certifications so please excuse any errors in writing here.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure you can trust the site, you could easily just skip certificate verification in wget with `--no-check-certificate`.

Aside from that, what you would need to do is to pull the correct chain via whatsmychaincert.com (it'll show you the correct one when you search for that domain), and then specify that wget should use it with the `--ca-certificate` flag.

Assume you save the chain as chain.crt, you would run `wget --ca-certificate chain.crt https://datashare.is.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/10283/3192/CINIC-10.tar.gz`.

Comment: +1 for the `--ca-certificate chain.crt`

That was the needed bit for me.

Answer (score 1):

The URL you mention redirects from `datashare.is.ed.ac.uk` site to `datashare.ed.ac.uk` site.

The intermediate certificate for `datashare.ed.ac.uk` is not presented by the webserver. You need to install the intermediate certificate "QuoVadis Europe EV SSL CA G1" and append it to the host certificate file, then restart apache service.

Here is the test for the broken web site.
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=datashare.ed.ac.uk&hideResults=on